# Network interface does not become active although onboot enabled, Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

Due to some other conflicts, I disabled/stopped NetworkManager in Fedora 15.

Now, for network configuration I used system-config-network-gui to config & enable Ethernet interface.

Problem is, when the system starts, the Ethernet does not become enabled.
Although in configuration through system-config-network I specifically checked:

"Activate device when computer starts"

"Allow all users to enable and disable the device"

and cleared "Controlled by NetworkManager"

I double checked the config file "/etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/ifcfg-eth0" to see if the configurations are saved correctly and onboot is enabled. And they look OK.

So, Why does it still not become enabled automatically on boot?

Comment: in file, /etc/sysconfig/network, I have `NETWORKING=yes`

Comment: you need to `chmod +x /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` so it can be enabled at boot. I could be wrong with the file name thou .. never used Fedora 15

Comment: Thanks WeloSefer, but I'm looking for a proper way to do so, not a hack. the current permissions are
 `-rw-r--r--. /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

Comment: It's not a hack. For my system, whenever I need some script to be included on boot, I enable execute bit on the file and add a line to my `rc.local` file which looks something like this `if [ -x /etc/rc.d/rc.vnstat ]; then
  /etc/rc.d/rc.vnstat start
fi`. That line ensures the script is included at boot. By looking at the file permission you included, execute is not set for any user so the first thing you should try is `chmod +x` and reboot the system.

Comment: Thans WeloSefer, I got a better answer in [Unix&Linux stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61375/network-interface-does-not-become-active-although-onboot-enabled) it was a linux bug, in [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=698738)